# Cross-Origin Embedder Policy and loading javscript

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I have a website on server A with *Cross-Origin Embedder Policy = RequireCorp* header that fetches a script from server B (A and B are different origins and both owned by me).

- There are multiple servers like A with different domains that need to fetch this script from B

I'm receiving the following error:
**net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200**

I see two ways to fix this:

1. Add Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy cross-origin header to server B.
2. Add crossorigin tag to this specific script tag

What are the differences between those two solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you own both servers, the difference is probably not so big, because CORS is about preventing cross-origin requests from a malicious website to a victimized server.

With alternative #1, the [`Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy) header must have the value `cross-origin`, which you may not want to set in general, but depending on the `Origin` header of the request.

With alternative #2, the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header could have a more restricted value like `https://serverA.of.your.website`. By this you could better restrict access without having to evaluate the `Origin` header of the request. But since you have multiple such servers A, that does not help you much.

Comment: So in case my Access-Control-Allow-Origin is already pretty allowing on server B what are the differences between the two methods? Even tho I control the servers I prefer to treat server A as such that can be compromised

Comment: Seems like (2) will allow A to fetch only this particular script while (1) will allow A to fetch any script if the crossorigin tag will be added to it so seems like (2) is safer

Comment: Even with (1), server B could add the `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin` header for certain scripts, but not for others.